# Cls/class values in fileuploadfield extjs component

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Out test automation team need HTML class/cls values in the **fileuploadfield** component that we are using.

Below is how we use it. I have put a value for **cls** in the below code but it is nowhere to be seen.

```
flex: 1,
xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
itemId: 'fileupload-field',
anchor: '100%',
textfieldWidth: 40,
emptyText: 'Select a document to upload...',
buttonText: 'Browse ',
cls: 'file-upload', //??

listeners: { //chop out directory string
    change: function(fld, value) {
        var newValue = value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/g, '');
        fld.setRawValue(newValue);
    }
}
```

How is it possible to get a cls value on the text field and the button on this component?

**UPDATE** : I managed to find the 'file-upload' on the HTML table for this component. All I need is cls values on the button and textfield.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of several config parmeters of the filefiled.Please check this once

```
{
            xtype: 'filefield',
            name: 'photo',
            fieldCls:'YourTextFieldClass',//Your textfield class
            fieldLabel: 'Photo',
            labelWidth: 50,
            msgTarget: 'side',
            allowBlank: false,
            anchor: '100%',
            buttonConfig:{
            text:'Your button', 
            cls:'buttonclass'//Your button class
          }

        }
```

Please check the documentation for more information.Hope it helps you.

Comment: the fieldCls works for the textfield, but the cls doesn't work for the button. But I am using 'fileuploadfield' instead of 'filefield'. SO maybe thats the difference :)

Comment: @OliverWatkins both are same.And i verified that I am able to see the class I added.{
            text:'Uplaod File ',
            cls:'uploadbuttoncls'
          },  class="x-btn uploadbuttoncls x-form-file-btn x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon"